# R- can I force close a shared (network) file using R?

Tags: r, excel, file, forceclose

I have an excel file that sits in a shared drive (MS One drive) and I would like to run an R script that updates some data in that file.
Is there a control in R to force close any open instances of that file so that the data update runs ok?

I have tried the close() and file() functions but without success.

Any ideas?

Thank you

Comment: Instead of forcing others to close, make a dynamic connection to a file from Excel. e.g.: R only updates mydata.xlsx, users use shared myFile.xlsx that has a connection to mydata.xlsx.